# continuous error with jenkins using pipeline

Tags: jenkins, devops

| header 1 | header 2 |
| --- | --- |
| cell 1[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xw344.png) | cell 2[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIpQM.png) |
| cell 3[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Imlo.png) | cell 4[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/712xm.png) |

I am new to jenkins and im creating a project using pipelin when i put the  script in jekinsfile its giving me error. Also attaching the script from jenkins file[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiSzl.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Also please post over on [Devops SE instead, that's the right community for this](https://devops.stackexchange.com/). (And there's no such thing as `nohup` on Windows. See also [this](https://devops.stackexchange.com/)).